# How can I query Facebook for the users twitter account?

Tags: facebook

Which permission would allow me to access the users Contact info on Facebook so that I can get the users Twitter account?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this information isn't available through the graph. To check, I used the Graph Explorer, granted every permission possible, and checked the resulting object for /me and that was not there.

Comment: Correct, screen names are not exposed via the API